# removing rows of pandas input file.

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading  files in pandas for which column names are not starting with row number one , instead there is headline/name row 1 of  data.csv

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
>>> df
  Unnamed: 0 Unnamed: 1  name Unnamed: 3
0       col1       col2  col3       col4
1          1          2     3          4
2          2          5     4          6
```

In this case  how i can delete row with headlines/names and make sure actual column names are col1, col2 etc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a `skiprows` parameter to [`read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) - presumably you just need `skiprows=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can choose to skip rows:**

You can choose specific line numbers to skip or a quantity of lines to skip. If you use specific row numbers, then pass a list to `skiprows`. In your case you could use the following to be certain things are read correctly:

`pd.read_csv("data.csv",header=[0], skiprows=[0])`

**Data:**

I used the following data stored in a file called data.csv

```
,,name,
0,       col1,       col2,  col3,       col4,
1,          1,          2,     3,          4,
2,          2,          5,     4,          6
```

**Output:**

```
0         col1         col2    col3         col4  Unnamed: 5
0  1            1            2       3            4         NaN
1  2            2            5       4            6         NaN
```

**From the docs:**

*Line numbers to skip (0-indexed) or number of lines to skip (int) at the start of the file.*

**Link to source:**

Here is a [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) to the documentation for your reference.

Comment: Did you run the code? `pd.read_csv("data.csv",header=[0], skiprows=[0])` loads all the values to be `NaN`

Comment: If down voting please leave a comment so I can improve my response.

Comment: @HarvIpan I added an edit tobe more specific but I have not had issue with the syntax I have included in my answer.

Comment: Not all files are with unwanted row. I have logic to check if row is unwanted or not. I have to read/load  csv twice (to check number of unwanted rows then reload with skiprows) . Can this be avoided?

Answer (score 1):

Considering your data is in `data.csv`, you can use below code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", skiprows=1)
```

Output:

```
    col1    col2    col3    col4    Unnamed: 4  Unnamed: 5  Unnamed: 6
0   1        2       3       4      NaN          NaN          NaN
1   2        5       4       6      NaN          NaN          NaN
```

Remove the unwanted columns with

```
df = df.dropna(axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   col1 col2 col3 col4
0   1    2    3     4
1   2    5    4     6
```

As @jpp pointed out you can also achieve these in one step as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", skiprows=1, usecols=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'])
```

Refer to [read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), [dropna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) for more information.

Comment: Even better if you have additional unwanted columns, use `usecols` parameter in `pd.read_csv`.